# Compare two sub strings for the strings which are available in two different arrays

Tags: perl

When comparing two directories of filenames I need to compare the names by only a substring in each name.

There are two folders and I have taken those two folders files into two different arrays.

The scenario here is that the filenames are same except time stamp so I have to take the sub string from each file name in two different folders/arrays and need to compare only sub string. And I have to print the unmatched file names based on the sub string comparison.

I have tried below code but displaying all the lines. Please help me where I have to modify my code. Thank you.

E.G. file names:
array1:

```
Statement.Inc.2017.1.2018-05-10-0349.Full.txt
Statement.Inc.2018.1.2018-05-10-0349.Full.txt
```

array2:

```
Statement.Inc.2017.1.2018-05-15-0351.Full.txt
Statement.Inc.2018.1.2018-05-15-0351.Full.txt
```

Code

```
my $sdipath="/home/ec2-user/TRF_DATA/FinancialStatement/FINALSDI";
my $sparkpath="/home/ec2-user/TRF_DATA/FinancialStatement/FINALSPARK";
my @a=`ls $sdipath`;
my @b=`ls $sparkpath`;
my $flag;
foreach (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++)
{
  my $file_sub1=substr("$a[$i]",0,-25);
  for(my $j=0; $j<=@b;$j++)
  {
    $flag=0;
    my $file_sub2=substr("$b[$j]",0,-25);
    if ($file_sub1 eq $file_sub2)
    {
      #print"Hello";
      #print"$file_sub1 $file_sub2\n";
      $flag=1;
    }
  }
  if($flag==0)
  {
    print "$a[$i]\n";
  }
}
foreach (my $i = 0; $i < @b; $i++)
{
my $file_sub2=substr("$b[$i]",0,-25);
for(my $j=0; $j<=@a;$j++)
{
  $flag=0;
  my $file_sub1=substr("$a[$j]",0,-25);
  if ($file_sub2 eq $file_sub1)
  {
    #print"Hello";
    #print"$file_sub1 $file_sub2\n";
    $flag=1;
  }
}
if($flag==0)
{
  print "$b[$i] is missing in SDI file\n";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing me with a `foreach` written as a `for` maybe that's breaking it, but lets assume it's working like `for` for now:

So E.G. your expecting that you won't output everything, but with your sample input it seems it should output something like:

`"Statement.Inc.2017.1" eq "Statement.Inc.2017.1"` when `$i=0 and $j=0`
So `$flag=1`
`"Statement.Inc.2017.1" ne "Statement.Inc.2018.1"` when `$i=0 and $j=1`
So `$flag=0`
▸ Exiting the inner loop with `$flag==0` will print `$a[$i]`
`"Statement.Inc.2018.1" ne "Statement.Inc.2017.1"` when `$i=1 and $j=0`
So `$flag=0`
`"Statement.Inc.2018.1" eq "Statement.Inc.2018.1"` when `$i=1 and $j=1`
So `$flag=1`
▸ Exiting the inner loops with `$flag==1` will not print

Giving the output:

```
Statement.Inc.2017.1.2018-05-10-0349.Full.txt
```

Then you swap foreach loops the same conditions apply but your output changes to:

```
Statement.Inc.2017.1.2018-05-15-0351.Full.txt is missing in SDI file
```

Since you don't seem to explain quite what you desired for all the comparisons… I don't know what if anything to "fix". But you should.
Like how there's no point in the quoting you're doing inside the `substr` functions, and how you probably wanted to set the `$flag` to `0` in the outer loops rather than inner loops. And then you might have also just used `if(!$flag)`.

## Besides, you probably want a simpler approach like:

```
my @a=`ls /home/ec2-user/TRF_DATA/FinancialStatement/FINALSDI`;
my @b=`ls /home/ec2-user/TRF_DATA/FinancialStatement/FINALSPARK`;

# Either you wanted:
my @pairs = map{ my $x = $_; map { [$x, $_] } @b } @a;
foreach (@pairs) {
  my ($f1, $f2) = @$_;
  chomp $f1;
  chomp $f2;
  if (substr($f1, 0, -25) eq substr($f2, 0, -25)) {
    print "$f1 is like $f2\n";
  } else {
    print "$f1 is not like $f2\n";
  }
}

# Or maybe you wanted:
foreach my $f1 (@a) {
  chomp $f1;
  my $f=1;
  foreach my $f2 (@b) {
    chomp $f2;
    if (substr($f1, 0, -25) eq substr($f2, 0, -25)) {
      $f=0;
      break;
    }
  }
  print "$f1\n" if $f;
}
foreach my $f2 (@b) {
  chomp $f2;
  my $f=1;
  foreach my $f1 (@a) {
    chomp $f1;
    if (substr($f1, 0, -25) eq substr($f2, 0, -25)) {
      $f=0;
      break;
    }
  }
  print "$f2 is missing in SDI file\n" if $f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any way I have resolved the issue my self.

Comment: @nmkishore Great; but this site usually encourages Q & A that are helpful to others too, so you might want to clarify what the issue was and how it was resolved and which of the two kinds of folder comparisons I showed was the one you were looking for.